# Why does Greek "ναι" mean "yes" while it comes from a PIE root meaning "no"?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, greek

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%B9), the Greek word *ναι* comes from Ancient Greek *ναί*, which is a variation of *νή*, which comes from Proto-Indo-European *ne*, which means *no*.

Why can a word have the opposite meaning to its origin? Or was Wiktionary wrong here, and this word actually comes from another language?

Comment: If the etymology is true, perhaps, from something like, "isn't it"? In Slavic languages, you can add "ne?" for a confirmation of a statement you think is probably true.

Comment: Hoffman's etymological dictionary of Greek does derive it from *nē, and linkes to Latin nē "truly".

Comment: Wiktionary doesn't say all of that. The entry for *νή* says “From the same source as Latin nē, enim.”

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler Yes, that's right. But in the page of Latin *nē*, it is said that the word is from PIE *ne, so I reduce it for the sake of the briefness.

Comment: @huy-ngo There are two etymology sections in the Latin page; you are quoting the first one, but it is the second one that is related to Greek *ναί*.

Comment: There is an interesting parallel in Brazilian Portuguese: “Pois não” means “definitely yes” and not “but no” as one would assume.....!

Comment: @JurgenBuschek - And "pois sim" is a negative, in kind of a "you must be kidding" way, instead of "so yes". But both are mainly used in answering a request, not a question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lat. *nē* 'really, true' and Tocharian B *nai* 'indeed, surely' seem to be the IE-parallels. The IE demonstrative *(h<sub>1</sub>e-)no- 'he there, that one' seems to be the root according to Beekes (with a questionmark though) and Babiniotis.

Comment: Actually, Beekes peppers it all with "?" and "could be". A hypothesis rather than a matter of agreement.

Comment: Several Slavic langues have _ano_ "yes" < = contraction from _a ono_ "and that", where demonstrative _ono_ "that" is probably related to *h1e-no? the construction looks like a Slavic innovation and has nothing to do with the Latin/Greek _nē_; what are their arguments for *(h1e-)no-, do they maybe cite Slavic constructions such _ano_?

Comment: Oh, and also, _ano_ is further reduced to _no_, so _nai_ could be a shortening from a longer form, too

Comment: @fdb: You're right. I made a note in the parenthesis.

Comment: @ConstantineGeist: Interesting. Babiniotis mentions the Slavic demonstrative na and Sanskrit na-na.

Comment: In Russian, _na_ means "here, take it" (when addressing several people, it takes the form _nate_ as if mimicking a verb). _ona_ means "she", which is most likely unrelated, but in Old Russian, _ona_ also meant "those" (plural neutrum). So _na_ is a contraction from _ona_? I'm not sure about the grammatical role of the ending (same for the Greek forms).

Comment: German has a discourse marker "na"--concessive or ironic: "na klar, na sicher doch, natürlich" (*bien sur, naturally*); likewise but more diverse depending on intonation, "naja" (*well …, comme ci comme ca, sure, not really*), apellative: "Na?" (*and? 'sup?*); overlapping with *nu* "now": *na dann mal los* (*so let's go; up and away*?); Gothic *ne-u-, n-u-* is a preverbal "question marker", isn't it? cp also Lat *nanciscor* "3. (by extension) I possess by birth, have by nature" < \*h₂neḱ- "to reach, attain" (cp *enough*, Ger *genug* vs *genau* "exact[ly]"), *necro* < \*neḱ-, En *dead certain*

Comment: *(h1e-)no- linked to ἐκεῖνος in Beekes.

Comment: One might think that words for "yes" and "no" would be fundamental features of languages, but actually they don't seem to be: many languages manage without them, and others which survived for long periods without seemed to evolve them at some point from whatever words came to hand.